# Internet Explorer - CSS style is applied only after refresh

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm quite new in web development. I encoutered a problem which is present only in the Internet Explorer - the CSS style of Main Menu is applied after refresh(just F5, not CTRL-F5). I used MVC .NET to make backend of site. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

The web site with this problem is:

http://jakubkowalczykart.com/

Thank you in advance.

@Edit: Cope snippet which reproduces problem. While opening in Chrome or Firefox it looks good, but in IE it doesn't

Style:

```
.main_menu {
    min-height: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 8vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.90;
    background: black; 
}
.menu_image {
    height:100%;
}
.menu_list {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 70%;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.menu_container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu_list {
    margin-right: 3vw ;
    height: 70%;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu_list li {

    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="body">

    <div class="main_menu" id="main_menu">
        <div class="logo">
            <div id="logo_img" ></div>
        </div>

            <div class="menu_container">
            <ul class="menu_list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="first_menu" class="menu_image" src="http://jakubkowalczykart.com/Content/Images/smallportfoliobutton.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img  id="second_menu" class="menu_image" src="http://jakubkowalczykart.com/Content/Images/smallshopbutton.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="third_menu" class="menu_image" src="http://jakubkowalczykart.com/Content/Images/smallaboutbutton.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img id="fourth_menu" class="menu_image" src="http://jakubkowalczykart.com/Content/Images/smallcontactbutton.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            </div>

    <div class="main_container" id="main_container">
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue.

Comment: Turn padding for everything off. That's what's messing it up in IE.

Comment: But in this simple example there is not any padding and IE still messes the website